# Fiori Notification center on HANA XS?

Tags: sap-fiori, s4hana, hana-xs

If Fiori Launchpad Site can be deployed on HANA XS directly from SAP Web IDE, then we do not need to install SAP NetWeaver for Fiori Launchpad with HANA XS? Is my understanding correct?

If yes, then what would be the Fiori version and how can we use Notification center feature on HANA XS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification center it's a functionality exclusive for SAP S/4 HANA, so there is no possibility yet to have notifications on SAP Fiori Launchpad sites from XSC or XSA.

Regards!
Matheus Goulart

Comment: Hello Matheus. Thanks for your response. Can you please tell, then how can we create dynamic launchpad tiles in HANA XSA. Regards, Shivam